# Is a caregiver allowed to pickup prescription medicine for elderly person living in assisted living center?

Tags: prescription, elderly-seniors-aged-old, health-policy

Is a caregiver allowed to pickup prescription medicine for elderly person living in assisted living center?

I am conducting research on this topic and writing a paper about it. Answer would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: This is going to depend tremendously on the location and on what the prescription is for. I doubt the age or living circumstances of the patient are relevant. I have picked up prescriptions for other people and they have picked them up for me, but all that demonstrates is that a handful of pharmacists are willing to hand over pretty mild things under some circumstances.

Comment: Short answer. If you are in the US, most likely, yes.

Comment: Pharmacies have their own policies; if a patient called the pharmacy to specify that an individual can pick up prescriptions for them, it facilitates it.